# Counting characters example in Programming Erlang, 2nd E

Tags: erlang

On pg. 82 of [Programming Erlang, 2nd E](https://pragprog.com/book/jaerlang2/programming-erlang), an example is given for producing a frequency map of characters in a string (actually applicable to counting elements of any list):

```erl
-module(count).
-export([count_characters/1]).

count_characters(Str) ->
    count_characters(Str, #{}).

count_characters([H|T], #{H := N}=X) ->
    count_characters(T, X#{H := N + 1});
count_characters([H|T], X) ->
    count_characters(T, X#{H => 1});
count_characters([], X) -> X.
```

Attempting to compile this, however, gives me:

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3.5.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(..., [{outdir, ...}]).
...
.../count.erl:7: variable 'H' is unbound
error
```

Where `...` is stuff I've elided.

This is actually noted as [errata #77244](https://pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang2/errata) on the book's website.

What's wrong with this code? What's the proper way to produce a frequency map?

Comment: please provide full source, We don't know line 7 in your source code is where

Comment: @bxdoan Done. I guess Tomasz's link answers the question!